# How to show json value in php page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

someone please tell me how we can show this value on php file via:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Here's my code:

```
varformData=new FormData();
formData.append("fieldname","value");
formData.append("image",$('[name="filename"]')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url:"page.php",
    data:formData,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:"JSON",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){ }
});
```

Comment: Please format your code and revise your question. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get value in php file like : json_encode($value); by my json code

Answer (score 2):

Use this for getting the posted data via the http body:

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // it's array.
```

Sanatize your input like below:

```
$sanatized = array_map('strip_tags', $values);
```

Use the sanatized array for inserting in database.

Comment: I want to use this value for insert value in database.

Comment: I want to get value in php file like : json_encode($value); by my json code

Comment: See my edit. Your input is json. For inserting in db, it's usable to decode json to array.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute data you get back from your success function is in json. So if you want to display whatever is inside you can simply access the keys by using a dot like so:

```
success:function(data){
    $("#empty_div").html(data.test);
}
```

If you used php the send back would look something like this:

```
$json = array();
$json['test'] = 'Hello';
return json_encode($json);
```

If you want to catch the data you are sending to your php file it will be in the post variable, because you made a post.

```
var_dump($_POST); //check what is inside
$data = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $data[$key] = $value;
//now everything is inside the $data array
```